# Test User logout in Django fails

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, logout, django-testing

I need to test if my user is logged out correctly. When I tried to logout, the test fails.

```
def test_user_logout(self):
    """Test user logout."""
    user = User.objects.create_user(username="test", password="test")
    self.logged_in = self.client.force_login(user=user)
    response = self.client.post(path=reverse("logout"), follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("login"))
    self.assertTrue(user.is_anonymous)                # this fails
```

My view method is:

```
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("login")
```

Comment: A `User` object, is never anonymous and never `is_anonymous`, etc. When you log out a user, the session data dissapears of the session, but the user itself does not contain any data that specifies if that user has logged in...

Comment: Thanks for answer, I see. Is it enought assert cases for this test case?

Comment: there is a `LogoutView` that does exactly that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView (except that it also contains logic to flush the sessions, etc.). This is tested by Django, so I don't really see the need to implement one yourself. Since this is tested by Django itself, then it is no longer your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `User` object does not hold if that user is logged in (in any session). Logged in is *session-oriented*, not *user-oriented*, so that means that for a given session you are logged in, if the session variables refer to a user. A `User` can thus be logged in in multiple sessions at the same time.

For a [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) object, [**`is_authenticated`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous) will always be `True`, and [**`is_anonymous`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) will always be `False`, regardless whether there is any session where you have logged in.

Django however has already a [**`LogoutView`** view <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView). It is the responsibility of the developers of Django to test this view effectively. Your `logout_view` can thus be replaced with this view. You can set the [**`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL) to:

```
# settings.py

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

and then use `LogoutView.as_view()` in the urls as view to log out.

Usually it is better to work with logical components that are already implemented by Django, this moves the burden of implementing, testing, maintaining and bugfixing from you to the Django developers, and since a lot of users use these views, it is likely that mistakes will be detected and fixed more effectively.